# filepicker.exportFile() with basic authentication

Tags: security, filepicker.io

I would like to download a file directly to my Google drive using the filepicker API. The file requires a username and password. I would expect filepicker's exportFile function to allow these to be passed in as arguments, but that does not seem to be the case:

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#export

The documentation is not explicit about why providing the credentials via this function is not allowed:

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/

My question is two-fold:
1) Does anyone know why filepicker does not allow direct passing of credentials
2) Is there an alternative way of uploading a file that requires basic authentication to Google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't provide any way to pass authentication credentials to the filepicker.exportFile() command. Generally in these situations we recommend creating a unique URL for the file that is not password-protected, and then potentially deleting the link once the file has been exported if desired.